# Why TIN interpolation crashes in Qgis?

Tags: interpolation, contour, qgis

I am using  TIN Interpolation to elaborate a DEM from contour lines. I don't understand why it crashes. The map extent is quite small and therefore it is not memory related the issue.

How could I sort it out? or maybe I should use another tool to generate the DEM?

[image]